# Retrieve Arabic data from Twitter

Tags: python, twitter, unicode, utf-8, tweepy

I want to retrieve Arabic data from `Twitter`, Using `Python3.5` and `Tweepy`.

I find a program that works very well with the english or french language But For the Arabic language the tweets are decode.
for exp:

> \ u04f \ u04e \ u043e \ u0430 \ U0430 \ u044f

This is the programme :

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

ConsumerKey = 'Your_Consumer_Key'
ConsumerSecret = 'Your_Consumer_Secret'
AccessToken = 'Your_Access_Token'
AccessTokenSecret = 'Your_Access_Token_Secret'

tweets = open('Tweets.txt',mode='w',encoding="utf8",newline=None)

class listener(StreamListener) :

      def on_data (self , data) :
            tweets.write(data)
            print (data)
            return True

      def on_error (self , status) :
            print (status)

auth = OAuthHandler (ConsumerKey , ConsumerSecret)
auth.set_access_token(AccessToken , AccessTokenSecret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth , listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=['أحوال','الطقس','2016'])
tweets.close()
```

I used some functions , but I get errors :

- ***data.decode()*** I get an error *AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'*
- ***u(data)*** I get an error *NameError: name 'u' is not defined*
- ***track=[unicode('2016','utf-8'),unicode('الطقس','utf-8'),unicode('أحوال','utf-8')]*** I get an error *NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined*

Comment: With the program you posted, it looks correct for Python 3 (I'd drop the `newline=None`, though).  Do you get an error?  For example, `print` on a Windows console generally limits the Unicode characters supported, so it is also important to mention your Python version, OS, runtime environment (console or some IDE) and post a full traceback of any errors.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I found a solution http://pastebin.com/v0QhbzS4 it's suppose to work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code works very well

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import json
import sys

ConsumerKey = 'Your_Consumer_Key'
ConsumerSecret = 'Your_Consumer_Secret'
AccessToken = 'Your_Access_Token'
AccessTokenSecret = 'Your_Access_Token_Secret'

non_bmp_map = dict.fromkeys(range(0x10000, sys.maxunicode + 1), 0xfffd)

#tweets = open('Tweets.txt',mode='w',encoding="utf8",newline=None)


class listener(StreamListener) :
    def on_data (self , data):
        try:
            tweet = json.loads(data)['text']
            print(tweet.translate(non_bmp_map))

        except KeyError:
            pass

    def on_error(self , status):
        print(status)


auth = OAuthHandler (ConsumerKey , ConsumerSecret)
auth.set_access_token(AccessToken , AccessTokenSecret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth , listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=['الله'])
#tweets.close()
```